# Emacs: list of functions in current source buffer

Tags: emacs

SublimeText2 has a command Command+R (on the mac) that shows a list of functions in the current buffer. For example, i'm editing C code, then command+R opens a hovering window with the list of functions in the current source.

Does have emacs have something similar. I know it can be coded, but has it?

I guess one could use clang to output the function definitions and their line numbers, put this in new buffer with links to the original source.

But how?

Comment: The answer will depend on the major mode you're using (effectively, the language that you're editing). You mention C here; are there other languages that you edit frequently?

Answer (score 5):

It's `imenu`. Use `imenu-add-menubar-index` and then in the menu is a list of functions. Works for `c-mode`. Let's see if it works for R mode ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `imenu` as mentioned by Sapsi I like to use it with one of the completition libraries, for example with ido: https://gist.github.com/magnars/2360578 or with `helm` with `helm-imenu` [image: helm-imenu]